# Slick Grid Inline Edit Whole Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, datagrid, slickgrid

I wants to create a functionality like Editing a whole row in single click.
[image: grid something like i wants]

so is there any plugin like that for SlickGrid....

Comment: When you click on an editable cell, the whole row is editable. What other behavior are you expecting?

Comment: I dont wants functionality like a Excel provide. i wants to create some thing like that when i Click on Edit Row. the whole row will open in Edit mode and when i click on Save it will save the Value in database. i hope you better understand my question...

Comment: Umm - so you want to enable the edit-mode on the grid when you click a button. Then disable edit-mode and submit the grid when you click the save button? Did I understand that right?